# How to create a function with arbitrary parameters based on an arbitrary string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, eval, function-declaration

My end goal is: I want to create a set of truth tables, where each truth table corresponds to an arbitrarily defined boolean expression, which is originally stored as a string (like: "(var_1 and not var_2) or var_3" ). The string could have any number of operators.

This is easily achievable if I have a particular boolean expression in mind:

```
def evaluator(var_1,var_2,var_3):
    return  (var_1 and not var_2) or var_3

def truth_table(f):
    values = [list(x) + [f(*x)] for x in product([False,True], repeat=f.__code__.co_argcount)]
    return pd.DataFrame(values,columns=(list(f.__code__.co_varnames) + [f.__name__]))

one_truth_table = truth_table(evaluator)
```

But I want to do it for any function of any number of parameters, with any type of boolean expression. I will be iterating through boolean expressions as strings to create a series of truth tables.

I've been struggling with this all day. If I could get this snippet of code to behave as I want, then my problem would be solved.

```
def temp_func(boolean_expression_string,variable_names_list):
    return eval(boolean_expression_string)

# i have two strings: '(var_1 and var_2) and (var_3 or not var_4) or var_etc'
# and also: 'var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4,var_etc'

temp_func('(var_1 and var_2) and (var_3 or not var_4) or var_etc', input(list(eval('var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4,var_etc'))))
```

Running this the result is:

```
NameError: name 'var_1' is not defined
```

I included the whole back story in case I'm approaching the whole problem in a dumb way. Though you might guess that I'm just trying to get it to work, elegance isn't my top priority at the moment.

**Edit: the variable names are not uniformly defined, and can't be parsed according to some ordering, so this is another layer of difficulty to deal with**

Comment: Updated my answer to incorporate the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) can take two dictionaries of name to value mappings to use as the global and local namespaces, respectively, to run the expression in.

### New answer

*It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.*

The idea is to find all variable names by trying to evaluate the expression and catching the `NameError`. Note that we need to generate all variable assignments for the list of variables because python will *short circuit* the evaluation of `or` and `and`. For example, in `var_1 or var_2` we will not find `var_2` if `var_1` is initialised to `True`.

```py
def variable_names(expression):
    # list of found variables
    variables = list()
    while True:
        try:
            # generate all assignments for current variable names
            assignments = [
                {variables[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(vs)}
                for vs in itertools.product(
                    [True, False], repeat=len(variables)
                )
            ]
            # try to evaluate them all
            for assignment in assignments:
                eval(expression, None, assignment)
            # all of them work, can return
            return variables
        except NameError as e:
            # get next variable
            variables.append(
                re.match("name '(.+)' is not defined", str(e)).group(1)
            )
```

We then generate a list of dictionaries of assignments—exactly as in the previous method—and give this to `eval`, adding the result to the dictionary. The DataFrame can then be created from records.

```py
def truth_table(expression):
    # get variable names
    variables = variable_names(expression)
    # make list of assignments
    assignments = [
        {variables[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(vs)}
        for vs in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=len(variables))
    ]
    # get truthy values
    values = [
        {**assignment, **{"value": eval(expression, None, assignment)}}
        for assignment in assignments
    ]
    # make dataframe from records and supply column order
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=variables + ["value"])
```

### Old answer—fixed variable naming.

If all of your variables are named `var_1`, `var_2`,... you can give a list of their value assignments to `evaluator` and parse them into a dictionary

```py
def evaluator(expression, values):
    return eval(
        expression,
        None,
        {"var_{}".format(i + 1): v for i, v in enumerate(values)},
    )
```

and run it as follows

```py
evaluator( 
    "(var_1 and var_2) and (var_3 or not var_4)", 
    [True, False, True, False] 
)
```

which returns `False`.

The full code for computing a truth table from an expression is then

```py
def truth_table(expression):
    # get variable names
    varnames = set(re.findall(r"(var_\d+)", expression))
    # sort by index
    varnames = sorted(varnames, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1]))
    # get truthy values
    values = [
        list(x) + [evaluator(expression, x)]
        for x in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=len(varnames))
    ]
    return pd.DataFrame(values, columns=varnames + ["T/F"])
```

If you have *holes* in the list of variables—e.g. `(var_1 and var_3)`—you'll need to either rename them before calling the evaluator or change the evaluator to take a dictionary.